# How to make this float precision without using print

Tags: python, arraylist

I'm working on assignment, it's about numerical method regarding to trapezoidal rule

```
def trapezoidalRule(F,a,b,n):
  h = float(b-a)/n
  f_sum = 0
  for i in range(1, n, 1):
    x = a + i * h
    f_sum = f_sum + f(x)
  return h * (0.5 * f(a) + f_sum + 0.5 * f(b))

def f(x):
  return x**3

a = 2
b = 10
n = 512

print('%.16f' %trapezoidalRule(f, a, b, n))
```

And the output is

```
2496.0058593750000000
```

My question is, **how do i get a precission like that.. without using `print('%.16f' %trapezoidalRule(f, a, b, n))`**. I want to append the result to the list, with exact value like that.. 
I already tried to google it, but i found nothing related to this problem, can somebody tell me the solution if i want to it ?

Comment: If you want to print the extra 0-s at the end, formatting like you're doing right now is your only option. If you just want to round the number, check the `round()` function

Comment: so you're saying that there's no way i can append that exact value to a list ?

Comment: You want to store value of print statement in list?

Comment: 20 digits is more than the real precision of floats, so this isn't an exact value, just something close with zeros added. If you want higher precision, have a look at the `decimal` module.

Comment: Yes, exact output value @VishalUpadhyay

Comment: I've already try that, if I use decimal function, and let's say my output is "2496.005859375" without the '%.16f'. I wouldn't have exra zero like the output value i wanted.

Comment: `l1 = []`
`a = '%.16f' %trapezoidalRule(f, a, b, n)`
`l1 = [a]`

This might be stupid but try and let me know

Comment: @VishalUpadhyay somebody else have solved my problem
Thank you for stopping by and helping me out everyone!

Comment: I hope you undestand that the way you format a number for printing does not affect its internal precision. The float keeps its precision (or lack of depending on the perspective)  no matter what you do with format or print. Using `decimal` gives you wider control of the internal representation.

Comment: But for common, simple calculations, decimal is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your return statement in `trapezoidalRule` to be formatted with 16 points of precision, do note that this is going to cause it to become a string as if you cast it back to float you'll lose the trailing 0's.

```
def trapezoidalRule(F,a,b,n):
  h = float(b-a)/n
  f_sum = 0
  for i in range(1, n, 1):
    x = a + i * h
    f_sum = f_sum + f(x)
  return format((h * (0.5 * f(a) + f_sum + 0.5 * f(b))), '.16f')

def f(x):
  return x**3

a = 2
b = 10
n = 512
```

See the return line in `trapezoidalRule` so now if I print the exact output of `trapezoidalRule` like so: `print(trapezoidalRule(f, a, b, n))` with no formatting I get:
`2496.0058593750000000`

Comment: this is kind of answer i'm looking for, thank you so much sir!

Answer (score 1):

To increase precision try using `decimal` module

```
import decimal

def trapezoidalRule(F,a,b,n):
  h = decimal.Decimal(float(b-a)/n)
  f_sum = 0
  for i in range(1, n, 1):
    x = a + i * h
    f_sum = f_sum + f(x)
  return h * (decimal.Decimal(0.5) * f(a) + f_sum + decimal.Decimal(0.5) * f(b))

def f(x):
  return decimal.Decimal(x**3)
```

Comment: this is also true, i appreciate the answer